# Add Scrollbar to Visual Force, dependent on Window Size

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, console

I have a Console component which is a Visual Force page; this one opens up from a ribbon tab in the bottom and is by default attached to this ribbon menu. I have the ability to de-attach this one so it is basically a large popup window which is re-sizeable. I need to add scroll bars to this visual force page since it will hold multiple tables which different number of rows depending on user input. There is also a desire to have this window in full screen so I need to have some sort of re-sizeable scroll bar depending on the actual height/width of the window. 
I have a scrollbar but that is dependent on the Height I set, predefined: 
What I need is a way to set a scrollbar for my Outputpanel dependent on the height of the Window, can anyone help me with this? My layout structure is according to this:

```
<apex:PageBlock>
<apex:PageBlockSection>
<apex:OutputPanel>
***Scrollable content***
</apex:PageBlock>
</apex:PageBlockSection>
</apex:OutputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser isn't adding it automatically, check your apex page starter at the top - do you have scroll bars turned off because you're using it in the console?

Comment: Which attribute in the apex:page element are you talking about? I have the following: <apex:page controller="ControllerX" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">

Comment: Yeah - that's not it then.    You might have to do something in css or jquery then, as salesforce doesn't provide a way to do this in apex.

This is probably a good starting point:  http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah it is a shame this is does not seem to be supported in Apex. I will try out solving it with the suggested library or something similar. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, that is enough for me to accept your answer.